# How do I use 'Dynamic mesh preview' in Blender 2.81?

Tags: sculpting

A new feature called the **dynamic mesh preview** was added in blender 2.81 for the sculpt mode, but, I can't see a way of using it. I was trying to try it out but I don't know how to toggle this on or off. Any guide would be really helpful.

EDIT: It seems the preview doesn't work with multires and works with subdiv surf modifier instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit counter intuitive because there's nothing saying, *dynamic mesh preview*, instead this feature seems to only work with the grab brush, when you tick the **grab active vertex** checkbox in the brush settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: for some reason the preview doesnt show up for me in Blender 2.81a, did them move the option?

Comment: I don't know, but, I also can trigger it in blender 2.82a, maybe try to update blender?

Comment: @JorgeLuque , it seems to not work with multires, and only with subdiv modifier